# ADLS gen2 compatible filesystem

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

Is there any ADLS gen2 API compatible filesystem available?

We want to automate our ADLS writer and it will run on our build environment which doesn't have access to azure, is there any API compatible filesystem which we can use for our automation testing, we are using minio for S3 writer testing and looking for the similar tool for ADLS.

Comment: Are you looking to have some local filesystem which should behave as ADLS gen2 for your automation testing? Could you please explain the scenario.

Comment: @IpsitaDash-MT that's right, I am looking a tool which I can deploy in my build environment and I want to test my ADLS gen2 writer client using this tool.  Do to company policy, we don't have ADLS access from out build environment.

Comment: As per the research there are no available local setup for ADLS Gen2 Writer, if that suffice could you please accept the answer for the benefit of other community Members.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, could not find any local setup for testing available for ADLS gen2 writer client using any tools. Please feel free to post your question in All Questions - [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html).